# Facebook SDK 3.5 Login via App does not work

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am really confused right now. I try to login to Facebook from my App. This works fine, when no native FB App is installed. I get the Acces Token and can work with it. But if the device has installed the facebook app and the app gets started on theLogin request, I do not get a Acces token with the following exception

```
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215): com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash Djug8pU5w1DRPIxRaRf2N-4JniU does not match any stored key hashes.
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at com.facebook.Session.handleAuthorizationResult(Session.java:1078)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at com.facebook.Session.onActivityResult(Session.java:554)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at com.lochmann.fb.viergewinntmultiplayer.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:266)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215): com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash Djug8pU5w1DRPIxRaRf2N-4JniU does not match any stored key hashes.
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at com.facebook.Session.handleAuthorizationResult(Session.java:1078)
11-11 11:10:50.510: W/System.err(19215):    at com.facebook.Session.onActivityResult(Session.java:554)
11-11 11:10:50.515: W/System.err(19215):    at com.lochmann.fb.viergewinntmultiplayer.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:266)
11-11 11:10:50.515: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
11-11 11:10:50.515: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3363)
11-11 11:10:50.515: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3410)
11-11 11:10:50.515: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-11 11:10:50.515: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
11-11 11:10:50.515: W/System.err(19215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 11:10:50.520: W/System.err(19215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 11:10:50.525: W/System.err(19215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-11 11:10:50.525: W/System.err(19215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 11:10:50.525: W/System.err(19215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 11:10:50.525: W/System.err(19215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-11 11:10:50.525: W/System.err(19215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-11 11:10:50.525: W/System.err(19215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do really think I got the right Hash-key because:

```
public static String getKeyHash(Context context) {
    String returner = "";
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.lochmann.fb.viergewinntmultiplayer", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            returner = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("MY KEY HASH:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR", "NO NAME");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR", "NO ALGO");

    }
    return returner;
}
```

**returns `11-11 11:10:42.445: E/MY KEY HASH:(19215): 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=`**

My Settings in the FB Backend look like this:

[image]

Does anybody have a hint for me, what I am doing wrong or what i could try?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you call that method out of activity, it returns always wrong key hash [2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=]. Try to print it in your activity(oncreate). Actually don't know why, but it works for me. Hope to this helps someone..

Comment: Hi, thanks for teh answer, will give it a try monday. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, now there is a new Key generated, and SSO now works perfect. Next challange will be to find out why the friend (add as friend) dialog is not working.